# How to estimate point of jump in a regression model?

Tags: regression, probability, change-point

So non-parametrically it is observed that once the temperature hits approximately 300K, there is a jump in conductivity of a material. Now the estimate is noisy and seems to shift slightly based on the composition of material (very similar material but can be type A, B or C) and also on humidity (discrete levels: level 1, level 2... level 10).

Now I have data where the test was run several hundred times in different labs on different humidity and different material. I have enough observations for each material X humidity combination.

It is important to note that this jump is not always at 300, visually it seems to be 300. It is almost like an S shaped, but flatter on the edges and steep on the neck. Almost like a step function on the negative side ( low at below 300K levels and high at above 300K levels).

I am using a probit/logit function to model this jump where change in conductivity $\Delta C$ is regressed primarily against dummy $\mathbb{D}_{t>300}$. Now since 300K is a value I pick visually, I wish to obtain the value at which the jump makes most sense. Like varying the jump value from 275K to 325K and running regressions for each and comparing likelihood to obtain the most sensible model.

Is this correct approach? Is there standard theory that deals with such problem? Are there existing packages that does this? If this approach seems reasonable then I end up with a reference point like 305K that gives me the maximum likelihood among all models. How do I go about estimating the confidence interval around this estimate other than bootstrapping?

TLDR: In a standard regression model with a jump dummy as explanatory variable, can I vary the location of jump around a suspected value and then compare likelihoods to obtain a point at which the likelihood is maximum and thus the jump makes most sense?